# How to fetch discussion for a given defect using the Java Rally API

Tags: java, rest, rally

I am trying to determine how to extract the discussion data for a defect in Rally using the Java Rally API. Unfortunately I can find no help online or in the documentation that tells me how to do this. I am able to obtain the URL to the discussion data and return it as a JSON element but I am not sure how to take the final step of querying that URL to get the discussions as another JSON object - I'd really appreciate help!

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.*;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.*;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class ExtractDiscussions

{

public static void main(String args[]) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

    RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"), "myApiKey");
    restApi.setApplicationName("DANA Example");
    restApi.setProxy(new URI("myProxy"),"myUsername","myPassword");

    try {

        QueryRequest defectRequest = new QueryRequest("defect");

        defectRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID","=","DE123456"));



        defectRequest.setFetch(new Fetch());

        //defectRequest.setPageSize(25);
        //defectRequest.setLimit(100);

        QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(defectRequest);

        System.out.println(queryResponse.getTotalResultCount());
        JsonObject obj = queryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();

        obj = obj.getAsJsonObject("Discussion");

        JsonElement discussionLink = obj.get("_ref");

        System.out.println(discussionLink);

        //Code would go here to fetch the discussion using the discussion link

    }finally{
        restApi.close();
    }

}
```

}

My Results:

```
1
"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Defect/1321234562/Discussion"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a GetRequest on that URL, you will be given back the collection of Conversation Posts. Handy tips are in here: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/